# How to stop reload the data when user open second time Fragment or activity?

Tags: java, android

"Ex: In  flipkart when we open App, Home screen will load the data and when we go to next activity from home screen and again we come back to Home screen its not loading again "

Comment: i am using both

Comment: yes when i am navigating from activity or fragment it is reloading home screen

Answer (score 0):

Cancel all the tasks using lifecycle methods of Fragment: "onPause", "onStop" and etc (you have to choose one of them). [Fragment lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments).

Answer (score 0):

**Use onActivityResult**

Define constant

```
public static final int REQUEST_CODE = 1;
```

Call your custom dialog activity using intent

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Activity.this,
                    CustomDialogActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent , REQUEST_CODE);
```

Now use onActivityResult to retrieve the result

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        try {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

            if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE  && resultCode  == RESULT_OK) {

                //reload data here
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Toast.makeText(Activity.this, ex.toString(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }
```

In custom dialog activity use this code to set result

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
intent.putExtra("key", value);
setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
finish();
```

Answer (score 0):

While tap on bottom back button it will not reload, because it just finishes current activity and resumes home activity.

To prevent reload home activity while tap on back button from toolbar, you have to add

```
android:launchMode="singleTop"
```

to your home activity in your manifest file.

For more details refer [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode)

Comment: if i will navigate from fragment then?

Comment: You can check https://medium.com/@bherbst/managing-the-fragment-back-stack-373e87e4ff62, https://medium.com/@Zhuinden/simplified-fragment-navigation-using-a-custom-backstack-552e06961257... there are plenty solutions available on internet to to dhis.